# Editor.JS SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax-error, package.json, editorjs

I am trying to install [editor.js](https://editorjs.io) into my project, however, I keep running into the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

I'm able to load it through there CDN but for some reason this is not able to work.

Here are the troubleshooting steps I've done so far:

1. Add `"type":"module"` to JSON file
2. Add `type="module"` to vanilla js script
3. rollback version of node to v11.4.0 (this was recommended from another page through stackoverflow).

I've searched through stackoverflow and I'm not able to find a solution other then these. Any advice?

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div  id="editorjs"></div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

JS File:

```
import EditorJS from '@editorjs/editorjs';

const editor = new EditorJS();
```

package JSON File:

```
{
  "name": "editor",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@editorjs/editorjs": "^2.18.0"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You would need `<script type="module" src="index.js">` but your [browser would also need to support it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module). Without a bundler though, I think you're going to quickly run into more problems

Comment: Hey @Phil I did try that and it gave me this error "Access to script at './editor/index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Any recommendations on what bundler I should use and how to install it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the import statement if you are getting editor.js from a CDN.  In your JS file all you need is:

```
const editor = new EditorJS();
```

I fell over this myself.  I think the Editor.js documentation [here](https://editorjs.io/getting-started/) is misleading.  It starts by saying there are 3 ways to install editor.js, but then all the remaining examples assume you've used `npm`.